# patternTransform in svg not working for entire pattern

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Im using a pattern in D3 in order to place an image inside a node and I can succesfully render the image. I am using a flag sprite and just want to clip a small portion for each flag. I am to able to do this for 2/3rds of the image but for some reason, it won't display any part of the image below 110px. The image is 256 by 176.

```
javascript
        //canvas
    var svg = d3.select("#chartContainer")
        .append('svg')
        .attr("width", 400)
        .attr("height", 400)
        .append('g');

        svg.append("pattern")
            .attr("id", "us")
            ///should be transformed to the US coordinates but the Algerian Flag appears
            .attr("patternTransform", "translate(-128, -154)")
            //this correctly shows the Canadian Flag
            //.attr("patternTransform", "translate(-16, -22)")
            .attr("width", 16)
            .attr("height", 11)
            .append("image")
            .attr("xlink:href", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5258675/flags.png")
            .attr("width", 256)
            .attr("height", 176);

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("width", 16)
        .attr("height", 11)
        .attr("x", 50)
        .attr("y", 50)
        .attr("fill", "url(#us)");
```

Here is a codepen as well: https://codepen.io/andrewgi/pen/oBYMdp?editors=1010.

The image sprite can be seen here for the coordinates: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5258675/flags.png.

Comment: Ok I removed a large amount of code and so now there is only one rectangle. Hope this helps solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the easiest way will be to remove the `patternTransform` altogether and do the `transform` on the `<image>` instead.

```
svg.append("pattern")
    .attr("id", "us")
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 11)
  .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5258675/flags.png")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-128, -154)")
    .attr("width", 256)
    .attr("height", 176);
```

This sets up the dimension of the pattern to be 16×11, which will be used to clip the contained image. The `flags.png` image is then translated to the correct offset (e.g. -128, -154 for the U.S.), whereby positioning the U.S. flag to be shown as desired. Of course, this will also work for any other flag.

Have a look at the following snippet for a working demo:

```js
var svg = d3.select("#chartContainer")
  .append('svg')
    .attr("width", 400)
    .attr("height", 400)
  .append('g');

svg.append("pattern")
    .attr("id", "us")
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 11)
  .append("image")
    .attr("xlink:href", "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5258675/flags.png")
    .attr("transform", "translate(-128, -154)")
    .attr("width", 256)
    .attr("height", 176);

svg.append("rect")
    .attr("width", 16)
    .attr("height", 11)
    .attr("x", 50)
    .attr("y", 50)
    .attr("fill", "url(#us)");
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<div id="chartContainer"></div>
```

Comment: That got it, thanks! Any idea why the patternTransform wasn't working for the bottom half of the image? I still don't understand.